# Get() on array in settings from custom Form controller

Tags: forms, 8

I'm making a custom module with a form controller, that has a text_format field.
I'm storing the text_format value in my submitForm function like so.

```
public function submitForm(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->config('foundation.settings')
         ->set('infoblock_text', $form_state->getValue('infoblock_text'))
        ->save();
}
```

I'm attempting to retrieve that for the default value of the field like so

```
    $form['infoblock_text'] = [
        '#type'          => 'text_format',
        '#title'         => t('Infoblock text'),
        '#description'   => t('The body text for the infoblock on the front page'),
        '#format'        => 'full_html',
        '#default_value' => $config->get('infoblock_text'),
    ];
```

However it's empty. After performing a die(print_r($config->get('infoblock_text'))) I found that infoblock_text is actually an array and 'value' is the key that contains the text I need. This is what the die() statement returns

```
Array ( [value] =>
Text of infoblock
[format] => full_html ) 1
```

After seeing that I actually needed to retrieve the value element rather the entire array I attempted the following with no luck.

```
$config->get('infoblock_text', 'value');
$config->get(['infoblock_text', 'value']);
$config->get('infoblock_text')->value;
$config->get('infoblock_text')->value();
$config->get('infoblock_text')->getValue();
$config->getValue('infoblock_text');
$config->getValue('infoblock_text');
$config->getValue('infoblock_text');
```

So how would I actually retrieve the value of 'infoblock_text', when $config->get('infoblock_text') returns the entire array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the config like an array:

```
$form['infoblock_text'] = [
    '#type'          => 'text_format',
    '#title'         => t('Infoblock text'),
    '#description'   => t('The body text for the infoblock on the front page'),
    '#format'        => isset($config->get('infoblock_text')['format']) ? $config->get('infoblock_text')['format'] : 'full_html',
    '#default_value' => isset($config->get('infoblock_text')['value']) ? $config->get('infoblock_text')['value'] : '',
];
```

When accessing the array like this, it's always a good idea to check if the key is set. This avoids warnings in your log.